# Derivation of IV for CBC Chaining Mode

Tags: encryption, cryptography

Is there any secure way of deriving the value of IV for use in CBC mode (e.g. 3DES CBC) aside from randomizing the IV?

Answer (score 1):

NIST's [special publication 800-38a](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38a/sp800-38a.pdf) discusses methods for the generation of IVs in Appendix C. One method that is proposed there is to use a counter or nonce, encrypt it and use the result as an IV. Contrary to e.g. the CTR mode it is necessary that a potential adversary can not predict the IV.

There exist attacks if predictable IVs are used. See for example [this paper](http://www.springerlink.com/content/3bg9hmrd0hndk1fy/). (I'll try to find a more accessible version).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make them unpredictable (to anyone else) but ensure they won't repeat, you could just encrypt a one-block counter with a random key (generated once for each message key) to generate the IV.  Make sure you keep the counter in persistent storage.

Answer (score 0):

Anything that never repeats and have no structure will work (I don't see why unpredictableness should be important - as long as the messages are also authenticated (which they ought to be)).

If you know that you will never send more than one message per second, you could use the unixtime (hash it and use the first bytes).

If you might be running in multiple threads/processes/machines, you might need to include a threadid/processid/machineid.

If you have access to generating a GUID, hashing this and using the first 8 bytes might also be a good option.

Comment: You imply it, but should explicitly state that the IV also needs to be unique. Reusing an IV is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: A monotonic counter never repeats, but if I'm using it on multiple instances, it's not unique.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to look at counter mode, rather than CBC.  Counter mode allows random access to encrypted data and can be parallelized.